# Update using right function in Where statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update one table from another table using the last 4 digits of a column. Below is what I have that is obviously failing. Using SQL 2012

```
UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[table1]
SET column1 = (SELECT table2.column1
                FROM table2
                WHERE (dbo.table2.column2 = dbo.table1.column2)
                 AND (dbo.table2.column3 = dbo.table1.column3) 
                 AND (dbo.table2.column4 = dbo.table1.column4) 
                 AND (dbo.table2.right(column5,4) = dbo.table1.right(column5,4))
```

Comment: So, mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: SQL Server. There error I am getting is Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'right'.

Comment: put the `Right` around the `dbo.table2.column5`

Answer (score 1):

The right way to perform an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` in SQL Server is:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.column1 = t2.column1 
FROM [DB].[dbo].[table1] t1
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2
    ON t2.column2 = t1.column2 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    AND t2.column3 = t1.column3 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    AND t2.column4 = t1.column4 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    AND right(t2.column5,4) = right(t1.column5,4) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

Comment: With that I am getting : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Comment: Sorry spelling mistake on my part... The error I am receiving now is: Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 5
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN" in the equal to operation.

Comment: @MattZ71 then you'll need to tell me which columns are strings

Comment: Yes using SQL Server 2014 not 2012

Comment: All of the columns I am using for the query are Character strings. I am a newbie to sql, you may need to tell me what else to look for. Thanks in advance for the help with this.

Comment: New error is:   Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Comment: @MattZ71 then not all of the columns are strings, please give the right information

Comment: table2 column 1 is (int, not null) same column in table1 is (nvarchar(255), null)

Comment: @MattZ71 look, I updated my answer again. But if you have another int or something I'm out.

Comment: All used columns in table1 are (nvarchar(255), null). In table2 they are (char(40), not null) except for column which is (int, not null)

Comment: Query ran successfully but 0 rows affected

Comment: @MattZ71 Well, that's a problem with your conditions then, you'll need to check your data.